# How to apply css to div content based on regex

Tags: html, css, regex

I want to apply css to my div tags if the innerHtml of the div matches a regular expression. I am somehow unable to find the right search terms to google it. Please point it out to me if it has already been asked on SO.

```
//CSS:

#main div[/* regex here which matches Foo. It will make the div red */] {
    color: red;   
}
```

​

```
//HTML:
<div id="main">
    <div>This text contains Foo. It contains other stuff too</div>
    <div>Red color will not be applied to this div because regex doesn't match</div>
</div>
```

I have seen examples which match the attributes using regex. For example [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7wpnL/). I am just unable to find the right 'term' for the regex to match the contents of the div. I don't want to use Javascript and parse the text.

PS : I don't have to have this thing on IE,Safari,Opera, so anything specific to Chrome/Mozilla would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in CSS to find the content inside innerHTML. But it is possible to search a string for HTML tag attribute values.

For example:

```
a[href*='google.com'] {
  color: red;
}
```

You can do this simply in javascript with jQuery. 
Samples: http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples

Comment: Yup. I'll do that. Just wanted to try css.